# Haskell beginner

Tags: haskell, option-type

I don't understand why I get the following response from GHCi. Isn't `Maybe` a constructor function?

```
Prelude> :t Maybe

<interactive>:1:1: Not in scope: data constructor `Maybe'
Prelude> let e = Maybe 5

<interactive>:1:9: Not in scope: data constructor `Maybe'
```

Comment: Both answers are exactly right, but I also want to point out that `maybe` (lowercase m) *is* a function, of type `b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b`: "The maybe function takes a default value, a function, and a Maybe value. If the Maybe value is Nothing, the function returns the default value. Otherwise, it applies the function to the value inside the Just and returns the result." http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:maybe

Answer (score 26):

`Maybe` is a [type constructor](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Constructor#Type_constructor), and its two possible [data constructors](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Constructor#Data_constructor) are `Nothing` and `Just`. So you have to say `Just 5` instead of `Maybe 5`.

```
> let x = Just 5
> x
Just 5
> let y = Nothing
> y
Nothing
> :type x
x :: Maybe Integer
> :type y
y :: Maybe a
> :info Maybe
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a     -- Defined in Data.Maybe
instance Eq a => Eq (Maybe a) -- Defined in Data.Maybe
instance Monad Maybe -- Defined in Data.Maybe
instance Functor Maybe -- Defined in Data.Maybe
instance Ord a => Ord (Maybe a) -- Defined in Data.Maybe
instance Read a => Read (Maybe a) -- Defined in GHC.Read
instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in GHC.Show
```

`Maybe` is a type constructor because it is used to construct new types (the result type depends on the type of `a` in `Maybe a`), where such a type might be `Maybe Int` (notice, there's no type param `a` anymore, i.e. all type parameters are bound). `Just a` and `Nothing` are data constructors because they're used to construct instances of a certain `Maybe` type, for example `Just Int` creates instances of `Maybe Int`.

Another major difference is that you can only use data constructors when pattern matching. You can't say:

```
case foo of
     Maybe a -> ...
```

You'll have to say:

```
case foo of
     Just a  -> ...
     Nothing -> ...
```

Comment: It seems that reading the tutorial so far leaves me a bit confused between type constructor and data constructor. The syntax is the same and according to the attached paragraph from the tutorial Just a is also a type constructor (??)  Parameterized types are similar to "generic" or "template" types in other languages. A parameterized type takes one or more type parameters. For example, the Standard Prelude type Maybe is defined as follows:
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a

Comment: @DavidKramf update my answer. Keep me posted if you still find anything unclear.

Comment: @Ionuț G. Stan: the `a` in `b :: Maybe a` is not the same `a` you defined.  Perhaps you should use variables `x`, `y` instead of `a`, `b` to avoid clashing letters?

Answer (score 6):

`Maybe` is the *type* name. The constructors of that type are `Just` and `Nothing`, so an actual *value* of the Maybe type is either of the form `Just 5` (for cases where there is a value you want to return) or `Nothing` (for the empty case).

Comment: @delnan: Yeah, already fixed that. Thanks for catching it, though. I was thinking of OCaml.